# JPA com a API Date do Java 8

Tags: java, datetime, jpa, java-8

Com as diversas melhorias da nova API DateTime do Java 8, como eu devo instanciar uma Data para uma entidade no JPA? Já é possível,por exemplo, ter um campo YearMonth que a JPA controle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por enquanto, de forma nativa do JPA, ainda não. Mas irá suportar. Não sei se na especificação JPA 2.2 ou no JPA 3.0. Veja aqui a [especificação](https://java.net/jira/browse/JPA_SPEC-63) que foi proposta, mas sem resposta.

O que você pode fazer é converter tipos como explica [esse artigo](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/montanajava/archive/2014/06/17/using-java-8-datetime-classes-jpa). O JPA até fornece uma solução elegante para essas conversões.